# How to change C# Windows Forms label color for 1 sec and reset the label color?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I'm making "Who want to be a millionaire" game in windows forms. I want after clicking label to become orange and after that become green or red. When I try this it isn't work properly. Sometimes they changes there colour but most times they don't. I think i don't use right method for this.

Could you help me to find solution?

```
Answer_A_Text.BackColor = Color.Orange;
Thread.Sleep(1000);
if(IsAnswerTrue){
Answer_A_Text.BackColor = Color.Green;
Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
else {
Answer_A_Text.BackColor = Color.Red;
Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
{some code...}
Answer_A_Text.BackColor = Color.White;
```

Comment: The reason you don't see the changing of the color is because the thread.sleep. That blocks the thread and thus prevents the UI from updating. You could use a timer with a callback function

Comment: Either use a timer or an `async` method with `await Task.Delay(1000);` instead of `Thread.Sleep()`.

Comment: Call `Application.DoEvents()` before `Sleep`.

Comment: What you're really asking is how to modify visual state, delay, then modify it again. We have lots of questions with answers on Stack Overflow addressing that basic scenario. See duplicate. Note especially the (not-accepted) answers that use `await`; this is the ideal approach in the current version of .NET. Whatever you do, do _not_ use such techniques as calling `Refresh()` or `DoEvents()`. Those approaches are fundamentally flawed.